# SQLite - Assign a sequential number to each range of rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by, row-number

In my table every color has index, which defines color order inside country, in every country order may be different.

| country | color | color_order | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | green | 1 |  |
| Canada | green | 1 |  |
| Canada | green | 1 |  |
| Canada | red | 2 |  |
| Canada | red | 2 |  |
| Canada | yellow | 3 |  |
| Canada | yellow | 3 |  |
| France | red | 1 |  |
| France | blue | 2 |  |
| France | blue | 2 |  |

After removing one of colors (all 'red' rows), I need to re-number color_order for each country.
Expected result:

| country | color | color_order | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | green | 1 |  |
| Canada | green | 1 |  |
| Canada | green | 1 |  |
| Canada | yellow | 2 |  |
| Canada | yellow | 2 |  |
| France | blue | 1 |  |
| France | blue | 1 |  |

It should be something like nested loop to iterate through country/color, seems query should include:
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY color_order)

Any ideas please?

Comment: incomprehensible connection of color and country. maybe color numbers id? Or is the color number sorted by the name of the colors of the alphabet?

Comment: color is some abstract grouping attribute for other_data rows, and color_order allows to display every range of colored rows in desirable order inside each country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DENSE_RANK() is a window function that computes the rank of a row in an ordered set of rows and returns the rank as an integer. The ranks are consecutive integers starting from 1. Rows with equal values receive the same rank. And rank values are not skipped in case of ties.

My solution looks like:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, country, color, color_order, 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY color_order ) AS new_order 
  FROM table1
)
UPDATE table1 SET color_order = (SELECT new_order FROM cte WHERE table1.id = cte.id );
```

Answer (score 0):

uses a Common Table Expression (CTE) to first select the rows that you want to keep in the table (all rows where the color is not 'red'). The ROW_NUMBER() function is then used to assign a new color_order to each row based on the order of the color_order column within each country (partition). Finally, an UPDATE statement is used to update the color_order values in the original table to the new values computed in the CTE.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT country, color, color_order, other_data,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY color_order) AS new_order
  FROM your_table
  WHERE color != 'red'
)
UPDATE cte
SET color_order = new_order;
```

Comment: SQLite does not support updatable ctes.

Comment: @redeyes looks like exactly what I need, but is it works in SQLite? I'm getting errors 'no such table: cte' in db browser, and 'syntax error near "(" ' in my IDE